# PHP - importing settings in a form (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, import, export

I am trying to do some import / export option for a script (wordpress plugin) using the settings API .

the relevant part of the code is  :

```
function o99_brsa_options_page() {

    global $o99_brsa_options; // declare as global so we can access everywhere


$o99_brsa_options2 = get_option( 'o99_brsa_settings' );
$currentsettings = "";
    if ( isset( $_POST['import'] ) && trim($_POST['brsa_keep_settings_imp']) != "" ) {
    $currentsettings = base64_encode($_POST['brsa_keep_settings_imp']);
    } elseif ( isset( $o99_brsa_options2 ) && ( $o99_brsa_options2 != "" ) ) {
    $currentsettings = base64_encode( serialize( $o99_brsa_options2 ) );
    }
// continue a lot of settings ...

                    <!-- / IMPORT o99_brsa_settings[brsa_keep_settings_exp] -->
                    <p>
                    <form method="post" action="#">
                    <textarea cols="50" rows="5"  id="brsa_keep_settings_imp"  name="brsa_keep_settings_imp" /><?php

                    ?></textarea>
                        <label class="description" for="brsa_keep_settings_imp">
                        </br><?php _e('Import Data', 'k99-brsa-domain'); ?>
                        </label>

                        <input type="submit" value="Import" id="import" name="import" class="button-primary" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to import these settings?')" />
                    </form></p>

    }
```

the full code is here :
http://pastebin.com/uBHHxJYJ

I can just not find what am I doing wrong, and why is it not working, I am obviously missing something here ...

Comment: @doublesharp the problem is that somehow the data is not being imported ...after it is being  pasted in the field..